# Is there a way to use a variable obtained from javascript in java?

Tags: javascript, java

From what I read, I understand that Java and Javascript works differently but isn't there any method/ workaround to get a variable from JS to Java? I have a code that uses Javascript to convert an uploaded CSV file to an array and a Java code that can send data in a textbox to a database. I'm trying to make 1 JSP interface so you can simply upload the csv using `<input type=file"/>` and then it goes to the database.

I got this code to work so far, but it shows a textbox and I'd like to do it more directly (making it hidden works for now, but I need it gone from the code)

```js
function x() {


  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var arr = e.target.result.split(",");
    // Continue processing...
    document.getElementById("name").value = arr[0];
    document.getElementById("in-time").value = arr[1];
    document.getElementById("out-time").value = arr[2];

  };

  reader.readAsText(document.getElementById("input").files[0]);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="process.jsp">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="in-time" name="in-time" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="out-time" name="out-time" /></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Upload</p><input type="file" id="input"> <input type="button" onclick="x()">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

process.JSP

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>

<%
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String inTime=request.getParameter("in-time");
    String outTime=request.getParameter("out-time");

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb", "root", "1234");
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();

        int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into test(name,`in`,`out`)values('"+name+"','"+inTime+"','"+outTime+"')");
        out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

Comment: u can write an interface which converts to/from json

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I'm not sure on how that works

Comment: in javascript use JSON.stringify(variable) and in java ull probably want a package like jackson or javax.json to parse the string

Comment: @jonathanHeindl my problem is, i already managed to get the csv converted, but in order to send it to the database I need to assign the data i got to java,

Comment: well ull wanna read up on rest interfaces - though there might be a default way with jsp oO